# EF6 stored procedure - output direction parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, .net-5

What's the right way to run a EF6 stored procedure with output direction parameter?

```
List<MySqlParameter> parms = new()
{
   new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = "@FilterJson", Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input) },
   new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = "@OutputJson", Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output }
};

var response = ReportingDetail.FromSqlRaw(
   @"CALL p_detail_get(@FilterJson, @OutputJson)",
   parms.ToArray()
);
```

This code throws an error:

**MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'Only ParameterDirection.Input is supported when CommandType is Text (parameter name: @OutputJson)'**

Expected output is JSON, something like:
`{"rows_count": 7, "actual_page": 1, "pages_count": 1}`

The problem is not with a connection, other procedures with no output direction works fine. Defining a type of @OutputJson does not fix the issue - `MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.JSON` or `DbType = System.Data.DbType.Object`.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Have you tried to put string as Output type?

Comment: Do you mean DbType = System.Data.DbType.String? Sure, nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the MySqlConnector [disscussion](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/231#issuecomment-650591486), it is not possible to return output direction parameters through it. You can try to write ADO.NET code to omit this restriction.